# Tensorflow gradient null for VAE with custom transformation layer with numpy_function

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, gradient

I am new to tensorflow and I wanted to start with a modified version of the VAE implementation of the official [tensorflow tutorials](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/cvae). I modified it that way, that I am having a custom input layer in the encoder which does a transformation via a `numpy_function` and an output layer in the decoder which does the inverse transformation via a `numpy_function`.

My model looks like this

```
class NumpyLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, numpy_func, func_name, dtype, **kwargs):
        self.numpy_func = numpy_func
        self.func_name = func_name
        super(NumpyLayer, self).__init__(dtype=dtype, trainable=False, **kwargs)

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        output = tf.numpy_function(
            func=self.numpy_func,
            inp=[inputs],
            Tout=inputs.dtype,
            name=self.func_name,
        )
        return output

class Sampling(layers.Layer):
    """Uses (z_mean, z_log_var) to sample z, the vector encoding a digit."""

    def call(self, z_mean: tf.Tensor, z_log_var: tf.Tensor) -> tf.Tensor:
        batch = tf.shape(z_mean)[0]
        dim = tf.shape(z_mean)[1]
        epsilon = tf.keras.backend.random_normal(shape=(batch, dim))
        return z_mean + tf.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon


class Encoder(layers.Layer):
    """Maps MNIST digits to a triplet (z_mean, z_log_var, z)."""

    def __init__(
        self,
        latent_dim,
        intermediate_dim,
        original_dim,
        dtype: np.dtype
        **kwargs
    ):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.latent_dim = latent_dim
        self.encoder = tf.keras.Sequential(
            [
                MyNumpyEncoder(
                    units=original_dim,
                    dtype=dtype,
                ),
                ComplexDenseEncoder(
                    intermediate_dim=intermediate_dim,
                    latent_dim=latent_dim,
                    dtype=dtype,
                ),
            ]
        )
        self.sampling = Sampling()

    def call(self, inputs: tf.Tensor) -> tf.Tensor:
        intermediate = self.encoder(inputs)
        z_mean = tf.concat(
            [
                tf.slice(intermediate, [0, 0], [1, self.latent_dim]),
                tf.slice(intermediate, [0, 2 * self.latent_dim], [1, self.latent_dim]),
            ],
            axis=1,
        )
        z_log_var = tf.concat(
            [
                tf.slice(intermediate, [0, self.latent_dim], [1, self.latent_dim]),
                tf.slice(intermediate, [0, 3 * self.latent_dim], [1, self.latent_dim]),
            ],
            axis=1,
        )
        z = self.sampling(z_mean, z_log_var)
        return z_mean, z_log_var, z


class Decoder(layers.Layer):
    """Converts z, the encoded digit vector, back into a readable digit."""

    def __init__(
        self,
        original_dim,
        intermediate_dim,
        dtype: np.dtype,
        **kwargs
    ):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.decoder = tf.keras.Sequential(
            [
                ComplexDenseDecoder(
                    intermediate_dim=intermediate_dim,
                    original_dim=original_dim,
                    dtype=dtype,
                ),
                MyNumpyDecoder(
                    units=original_dim,
                    dtype=dtype,
                ),
            ]
        )

    def call(self, inputs: tf.Tensor) -> tf.Tensor:
        logits = self.decoder(inputs)
        return logits


class VarationalAutoencoder(Model):
    def __init__(
        self, original_dim, latent_dim, dtype, **kwargs
    ):
        super(VarationalAutoencoder, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.encoder = Encoder(
            latent_dim=latent_dim,
            intermediate_dim=self.intermediate_dim,
            original_dim=original_dim,
            dtype=dtype,
        )
        self.decoder = Decoder(
            original_dim=original_dim,
            intermediate_dim=self.intermediate_dim,
            dtype=dtype,
        )
        self.total_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="total_loss")
        self.reconstruction_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(
            name="reconstruction_loss"
        )
        self.kl_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="kl_loss")
    
    @property
    def metrics(self):
        return [
            self.total_loss_tracker,
            self.reconstruction_loss_tracker,
            self.kl_loss_tracker
        ]
        
    def call(self, inputs):
        _, _, z = self.encoder(inputs)
        reconstructed = self.decoder(z)
        return reconstructed

    def train_step(self, inputs: tf.Tensor) -> dict:
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            z_mean, z_log_var, z = self.encoder(inputs)
            reconstruction = self.decoder(z)
            reconstruction_loss, kl_loss = self.calculate_losses(
                inputs, z_mean, z_log_var, reconstruction
            )
            total_loss = tf.math.add_n([reconstruction_loss, kl_loss])
        grads = tape.gradient(total_loss, self.trainable_weights)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.trainable_weights))
        self.total_loss_tracker.update_state(total_loss)
        self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.update_state(reconstruction_loss)
        self.kl_loss_tracker.update_state(kl_loss)
        return {
            "loss": self.total_loss_tracker.result(),
            "reconstruction_loss": self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.result(),
            "kl_loss": self.kl_loss_tracker.result()
        }
        
    @tf.function
    def calculate_losses(
        self,
        inputs: tf.Tensor,
        z_mean: tf.Tensor,
        z_log_var: tf.Tensor,
        reconstruction: tf.Tensor,
    ) -> typing.Tuple[tf.Tensor, tf.Tensor]:
        reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(
            keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(inputs, reconstruction)
        )
        kl_loss = -0.5 * (1 + z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var))
        kl_loss = tf.reduce_mean(kl_loss, axis=None)
        return reconstruction_loss, kl_loss

def training():
    ...

    autoencoder = VarationalAutoencoder(
        latent_dim=latent_dim, original_dim=original_dim, dtype=dtype
    )
    autoencoder.compile(optimizer=optimizer, run_eagerly=True)
    autoencoder.fit(
        x=x_train,
        epochs=epochs,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        shuffle=True,
        validation_data=(x_test,)
    )
```

where at `ComplexDenseLayer` is just a wrapper for multiple `Dense` layers and `MyNumpy(Enc/Dec)oder` is just a wrapper inherited from the NumpyLayer with the corresponding transformation function.

Running the training now with my own random data works somehow and I am getting all the losses but tensorflow is throwing a warning at each step that there was no gradient for the decoder part → `tensorflow:Gradients do not exist for variables`. Stopping after the GradientTape section and checking the grads variable, I observed that all the decoder gradients are `null`.

Now, after reading the [Getting a gradient of none](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/autodiff#getting_a_gradient_of_none) section of the tensorflow docs, I just started naively and commented out the `MyNumpyDecoder` part in the `Sequential` of the decoder.

```
self.decoder = tf.keras.Sequential(
            [
                ComplexDenseDecoder(
                    intermediate_dim=intermediate_dim,
                    original_dim=original_dim,
                    dtype=dtype,
                ),
                # MyNumpyDecoder(
                #     units=original_dim,
                #     dtype=dtype,
                # ),
            ]
        )
```

After that change, I am seeing that all gradients are calculated.

I just thought that my implementation avoids the pitfalls of the "getting a gradient of none" description by using the numpy_function and compiling the model with eager mode.

What I am doing actually wrong?

Thanks and best regards

Comment: How do you expect Tensorflow to backpropagate through numpy functions with no defined gradients? It just doesn't work. You will either need to define custom gradients for the numpy functions (see `tf.custom_gradient`) or re-write it using differentiable Tensorflow operations. Since we cannot see what exactly you are doing with numpy, it's hard to tell which option would be better (or whether either is possible, at all).

Comment: Yeah, fair enough. I am using wavelet packets from pywavelets which are currently not available as a Tensorflow implementation. 
Frankly spoken, I am not totally aware of the underlying tensorflow implementation and just thought, it skips backpropagating for that layer if it is set to non-trainable. Btw, why is it working for the first custom layer? I would expect the same behavior here too.

Comment: As you say, the first custom layer (`ComplexDenseDecoder`) is just a stack of dense layers? Those are all differentiable TF ops so they can be backpropagated through. A non-trainable layer cannot be "skipped" since the gradients for the earlier layers still depend on this non-trainable layer. You could define a custom gradient for this layer that simply passes through gradients unchanged, but that would lead to wrong results since the forward and backward operations wouldn't match. I'm afraid there is no way around the aforementioned solutions, or removing the operations outright.

Comment: @xdurch0 thanks for the pointer. At least, I got the training now running without errors but I have to figure out a fitting implementation for the gradients. I am currently checking  `np.gradient` out.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`tf.custom_gradient`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/custom_gradient) decorator with the numpy function call will at least run the training with valid gradients for all trainable weights. A minimal implementation could just forward the incoming gradients, e.g.

```py
@tf.custom_gradient
def call(inputs, **kwargs):
    output = tf.numpy_function(
        func=self.numpy_func,
        inp=[inputs],
        Tout=inputs.dtype,
        name=self.func_name,
    )

    def gradients(upstream):
        return upstream

    return output, gradients
```

Comment: This should've been a comment and not an answer as this is not an answer.